# Using fastutill ObjectArrayList in Spark application throws exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using a fastutill ObjectArrayList[object] instead of ArrayBuffer in scala in my spark streamign applicatiuon (inside a mapwithstae function)

I use the lates version..using below sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "it.unimi.dsi" % "fastutil" % "7.0.13"
```

However, it throws an exception

```
yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/ObjectArrayList
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/ObjectArrayList
    at MapRRecoverableConsumer$$anonfun$5.apply(MapRRecoverableConsumer.scala:756)
    at MapRRecoverableConsumer$$anonfun$5.apply(MapRRecoverableConsumer.scala:293)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.getOrCreate(StreamingContext.scala:864)
    at MapRRecoverableConsumer$.main(MapRRecoverableConsumer.scala:863)
    at MapRRecoverableConsumer.main(MapRRecoverableConsumer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.ObjectArrayList
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok..just added as jars parameter in spark submit and it resolved that..